# when overriding method why is it necessary to write it in superclass first, even when it isnt meaningful for superclass?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, methods, overriding

when overriding a method, why is it necessary to write that method in superclass even when that method is of no use in superclass, so isnt it sufficient to override that methods in subclasses where its meaningful. for example if there is a superclass A, with two subclasses B and C, and I want to override a method D, which is meaningful only to subclasses B and C but not to superclass A, so why do we need to write that overridden method D in A, why cant we only write in subclasses B and C, when method D is not meaningful to superclass A.

Comment: What are you actually trying to use overriding for? You don't have to write your method in your superclass. You don't have to use overriding at all. Maybe you're looking for abstract methods, but without knowing what you're trying to accomplish, it's hard to say.

Comment: I suggest coding it both ways to see what happens. Write a method that takes an `A`. Pass in a `B` or `C` which overrides a method on `A`. Then remove that method from `A`. See what happens.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want an implementation in the superclass you could make the method and superclass abstract.

```
abstract public class A {
    public abstract void aMethod();
}


public class B extends A{
    @Override
    public void aMethod() {
    }
}


public class C extends A {
    @Override
    public void aMethod() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you make a super-class that is meant to be extended from (usually abstract)  many times it does not event need to use some of the methods in it, just the sub-classes, this is easiest to show with an example:

```
public abstract class GameObject {
        public abstract void render(Graphics g);
}
```

this is the super-class right now it currently has only one method `render`.
this super-class may have *many* sub-classes.

```
public class GameObject1 extends GameObject {
     @Override
     public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.drawsomething();
     }
}
```

sub-classes ^ ^ v v

```
public class GameObject2 extends GameObject {
     @Override
     public void render(Graphics g) {
        g.drawsomethingelse();
     }
}
```

would it be easier to make many lists for each individual type of sub-class or do something like this:

```
List<GameObject> objects = new ArrayList<GameObject>();

public void renderEverything(Graphics g) {
      for(GameObject o : objects)
          o.render(g);
}
```

the second example is much easier and faster that creating tons of lists for each sub class type